# Stripe SCA payments and secret key

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a website that takes card payments using Stripe.  Currently it uses the checkout API, but I am upgrading it to use the SCA API, and PaymentIntents.

I am concerned however that it appears that the PaymentIntents API requires you to present your secret key in order to create the session.

As I don't have my own servers, and am using hosted environments, I don't really want to place a secret key on these.

Indeed Stripe themselves say "Secret API keys should be kept confidential and only stored on your own servers. Your account’s secret API key can perform any API request to Stripe without restriction."

I have engaged with Stripe support, and they appear to be saying that yes, you can't use a restricted key, you have to use the secret key, but I don't like this!

Am I missing something, or going about it the wrong way?  Has anyone got PaymentIntents working without the secret key?

Comment: You don't need PaymentIntents API, Checkout has full support for SCA. You need PaymentIntents if you're running own backend and want to get full control on payment flow.

Comment: And no, you can't use PaymentIntents API without secret key. What do you mean by hosted environment? If you're renting virtual server from a hosting provider it's ok to store Secret Key there.

Comment: No, I mean shared web hosting environment, not a virtual private server.

Comment: You say that Checkout has full support for SCA - yes, but as soon as you follow the recipe for server integration, the first thing it seems to do is to create a session ... for which you need the secret key, and you can't use a restricted key for that ...?

(I dont think client integration works because you have to pre populate the dash board with your products .. and the price I calculate is variable depending on user input - it's not a simple 4-off items at cost x)

Comment: Yes, for Server side integration you need a secret key. You could use client integration, but in this case you have to manage your products on Stripe Dashboard page. Shared hosting (if you have something like Bluehost) is usually not that unsafe because of file access permissions. Also Secret key can't be used to stole someone's money - all the payments goes to your account anyway, so risks are limited. You can always revoke compromised secret key and request a new one.